# Stylesheet_link_tag is broken, paths to files not working, can't figure out why for the life of me. Any ideas?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm in Rails 3.1, config,assets.enabled is true in config/application.rb

I've got these that aren't working and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen.css', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print.css', :media => 'print' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

This doesn't work either (image doesn't show with abbreviated path to image or the full path)

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you put your images in `assets/images` directory?